# Algorithms to find the distance/similarity among the user tags?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I want to find the semantic/similarity of user tags.

Each user can use maximum four tags. For example, User-1["Machine learning", "Photography", "data science", "neural network"], User-2 ["Machine learning", "Data Science", "Statistics", "Mathematics"],  User-2 ["Geophysics", "Machine learning", "Art and printing", "Mathematics"].

Tags are from wide range of skills. I want to find the distance/similarity among the tags.  For example: "Machine learning," "Data science," and "neural network" will be close to each other, similarly "Photography" and "Art and printing" would be close to each other.

I was thinking to use word2vec. But I am hesitating to use it in production since I have to train it with thousand categories of skill set documents. Not only that in real life users always change/update their tags. So I want to build/develop a dynamic algorithm that will be adjusted according to user tag.

I am a newbie in machine learning world.

Answer (score 1):

Every tag can be presented as a BitMap(BitSet), a single bit represents a specific user has this tag or not. Then you can use some similarity functions like Jaccard or Ochiai